# JQuery ajax post to PHP server not working - "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to send json data to a server, and receive a json response, code is as follows:

JS:

```
function login() {

console.log("clicked");

//get values of form into variables
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();

//create data array
var dataString = {"email": email, "password": password};

console.log(dataString);

//check for blank inputs
if ($.trim(email).length == 0) {
    myApp.alert("Email required", "Login Failed");
} else if ($.trim(password).length == 0) {
    myApp.alert("Password required", "Login Failed");
}

//if form isnt empty, post ajax request to server
if ($.trim(email).length > 0 & $.trim(password).length > 0) {

    console.log("input checked");

    $.support.cors = true;

    //ajax post
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://gingr-server.com/login.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,

        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#login").val('Connecting...');
            console.log("connecting to server");
        },

        //display success/fail message - put something in data on server
        success: function(data, textString, xhr) {
            if (data.status == "correct") {
                localStorage.login = "true";
                localStorage.email = email;
                localStorage.id = data.id;
                mainView.router.loadPage("swipe.html");
            } else {
                myApp.alert("Incorrect email or password", "Login Failed");
            }
        },

        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            myApp.alert("Unknown error, please try again", "Login Failed");
        },

        complete: function(data) {
            if (data.readyState == "0") {
                console.log("unsent");
            } else if (data.readyState == "4") {
                console.log("done");
            }   
        }

    });
} 
return false;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
header("access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("access-control-allow-headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type");

header('Content-Type: application/json');

//include databse info
require_once "db_config.php";

    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]));
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]));

    //get hashed password from db
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT password, id FROM user_table WHERE 
    email = '$email'");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $passwordHash = $row["password"];
    $userID = $row["id"];

    //free memory
    $result->free();

    //verify password for that email
    if (password_verify($password, $passwordHash)) {
        $response = array(  "status" => "correct",
                            "id" => $userID));
    } else {
        $response = array("status" => "incorrect"));
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

The error message is as follows:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse ()

To me, it looks as if the client is receiving HTML (hence the < tag) instead of json, but I have no idea why!

Comment: Think your assumption is correct though.

Comment: I have seen that, it doesn't appear to be the same problem.

Mine has worked previously when the php contained echo json_encode(array("key" => "data"), but only sometimes, very weird!

Comment: Use console/network tabs to make sure you are seeing what is going across. If the client looks to actually be receiving JSON and not say some HTML then try a JSON lint tool to validate?

Comment: Alternate approach assuming hitting the right URL. Test the PHP page independently, does it serve the JSON?

Comment: Check headers tab what is the status of your request? Make sure it doesnt says the address moved...the link in your test code is not accessible or has error. turn on error reporting on php page by `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` And check response for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! Nothing clever at all...

```
$response = array(  "status" => "correct",
                            "id" => $userID));
```

spot the )); causing all the problems... Bed time I think

Comment: Glad you caught it! Always start with the logs. They are great at catching things like parse errors ;)

Comment: Good to know, however it seems you do not have display errors turned on. Turn them on to see the errors during development. Easier to catch errors.

Comment: @Motsim on it now, might be needed!